# Reproducing Hydrogen Molecule Hamiltonian in OpenFermion

Tags: chemistry, openfermion

I am learning quantum chemistry at the moment and I'm trying to understand the Hamiltonian generated by the [OpenFermion](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=openfermion) package. I'm now stuck at understanding how openfermion calculates the coefficients in second quantization Hamiltonians.

Take the for Hydrogen molecule for example. My understanding is that the coefficients

> - $h_{00}$, represents electron 1 in 1s orbit with spin up.
> - $h_{11}$, represents electron 1 in 1s orbit with spin down.
> - $h_{22}$, represents electron 2 in 1s orbit with spin down.
> - $h_{33}$, represents electron 2 in 1s orbit with spin down.

As the wavefunction of 1s orbits takes the form

$$\psi_{1s}(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-r}$$

The $h_{ii}$ should be

\begin{equation}
2\pi \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi}\psi_{1s}(r)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+R^2-2r R\cos\theta}}\right)\psi_{1s}(r)r^2 \sin\theta d\theta dr
= -1.07123
\end{equation}
when $R = 0.74$ Bohr radius, which does not match with openfermion's
\begin{align}
h_{00} &= h_{11} = -1.2524635735648988\\
h_{22} &= h_{33} = -0.47594871522096416\\
\end{align}

Can anyone tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic No, [quantumcomputing.se] is the home to questions on OpenFermion (explicit instructions on the [github page](https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion) under the "How to contribute" heading).

Comment: @Qmechanic their GitHub page might say that, but this question probably would have been answered by now at [MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/).